# How to use double hyphen in Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell

I've read about escaping `--` with the backtick, but it appears that Powershell is still evaluating my arguments incorrectly.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
$argList = "`--pack-extension=`"C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Chrome\Chrome\app`" `--pack-extension-key=`"C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Chrome\app.pem`""
$path = "'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'"
Invoke-Expression "$path $argList"

Unexpected token 'pack-extension="C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 
2013\Projects\Chrome\Chrome\app"' in expression or statement.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using single quotes surrounding the entire string seems to get me further in that the error now includes `--`, but it still says Unexpected token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$argList = @(
  '--pack-extension="C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Chrome\Chrome\app"'
  '--pack-extension-key="C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Chrome\app.pem"'
)
$path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
& $path $argList
```

http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right